# How to correctly set Hunpos tagger in NLTK for POS tagging in english?

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I'm trying to use the [Hunpos tagger](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.hunpos) for POS tagging with NLTK instead of the traditional `pos_tag()`, but I'm having some trouble with loading the binary `english.model` or `en_wsj.model`.

In fact, I'm in linux mint and I put them in `/usr/local/bin`, set the `HUNPOS` environment variable to this path, and even tried to pass this path to the parameter `path_to_bin` used in the `__init__` of `nltk/tag/hunpos.py` file, but when it recognizes the file, it throws this error:

```
>>> ht = HunposTagger('en_wsj.model','/usr/local/bin/en_wsj.model')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg/nltk/tag/hunpos.py", line 89, in __init__
    shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Does anyone got an idea about what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found a way to do it. For those who were having the same problem, I recommend you to download the source code, build it and call it in a way different from what is described in NLTK docs. As it weren't trivial for me, I'm putting it here step-by-step:

Under Unix:

1) Download [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) SVN if you don't have it and check out the project source code:

```
svn checkout http://hunpos.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ hunpos-read-only
```

This will create a `trunk` directory where you checked out.

2) Then, to be able to successfully build it, you might need `ocamlbuild` for automatic compiling of Objective Caml. `sudo apt-get install ocaml-nox` should handle this.

3) `cd` to the `trunk` directory (where you downloaded Hunpos source code) and do

```
./build.sh build
```

4) At this point, you shall have a binary file `tagger.native` in your `trunk` directory. Put the whole `trunk` directory in your `/usr/local/bin` (you may need to do it as super user).

5) Download the `en_wsj.model.gz` file [here](https://code.google.com/p/hunpos/downloads/list), unzip it and put the `en_wsj.model` binary also in `usr/local/bin`.

6) Finally, in your python script, you may create an instance of `HunposTagger` class passing the paths to both files you have created previously, something very close to:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
>>> ht = HunposTagger(path_to_model='/usr/local/bin/en_wsj.model', \
                      path_to_bin=  '/usr/local/bin/trunk/tagger.native')
>>> ht.tag('I want to go to San Francisco next year'.split())
[('I', 'PRP'), ('want', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('go', 'VB'), ('to', 'TO'),
 ('San', 'NNP'), ('Francisco', 'NNP'), ('next', 'JJ'), ('year', 'NN')]
>>> ht.close()
```

(Don't forget to close... if you don't like to close, you may use the `with` statement as well)

7) If you still have some trouble, try to set an environmental variable `HUNPOS` to `/usr/local/bin/trunk`. To do this, you may add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` in MacOS):

```
export HUNPOS=/usr/local/bin/trunk
```

and restart your terminal.

That worked for me, but if someone has a better, shorter or simpler way to set this up, please I'd love to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-compiled versions of hunpos where you can use immediately without compiling from source if you're working on linux.

```
$ wget https://hunpos.googlecode.com/files/hunpos-1.0-linux.tgz
$ wget https://hunpos.googlecode.com/files/en_wsj.model.gz
$ tar xvfz hunpos-1.0-linux.tgz
$ gunzip en_wsj.model.gz
$ mv en_wsj.model hunpos-1.0-linux
$ python
>>> from nltk.tag import HunposTagger
>>> hpt = HunposTagger('hunpos-1.0-linux/en_wsj.model','hunpos-1.0-linux/hunpos-tag')
>>> hpt.tag('this is a foo bar sentence'.split())
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'JJ'), ('bar', 'NN'), ('sentence', 'NN')]
```

Comment: Generally I prefer pre-compiled versions too, but when I tried it 6 months ago either it didn't work or I needed to make some little changes in the code, I can't remember which one of them. That's why I tried to compile the tagger.